# PHP on IIS with Plesk, write permission denied

Tags: php, iis, permissions, plesk

I have a PHP website running on IIS with plesk. Everything works fine except I can't grant write access for php scripts.

All permissions on folders for the web user (SDadmin******/IUSR_user****) are set to on for  writing.

Launching a basic testing script that creates both a folder and a file I get:

**PHP Warning:  file_put_contents(test_file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.xx\httpdocs\in.php on line 4**

**PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in D:\Inetpub\vhosts\xxxxxxx.xx\httpdocs\in.php on line 11**

I already spent a whole day of googling, reading a bunch of topics and trying almost every possible tip found on internet but with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the file/directory permissions?

Comment: I did. For every user, every folder and file in them.

Comment: I did. My only concern is if I should apply the same permissions for the parent folders (/vhosts)

Comment: which IIS version is this? assuming it's >= 7. The IIS user is called IIS_IUSRS (MachineName\IIS_IUSRS) is that the user that has write permissions on the folder?

Answer (score 2):

Has you domain "Additional write/modify permissions" checked?

[image: plesk-windows-php-write-permissions]

Comment: Hm. You can try "Correct disk permissions" in "Plesk Reconfigurator"(it's a desktop tool, you can find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\admin\bin\reconfigurator.exe )

Comment: Launched plesk reconfigurator. It runs with no issues, but seems like the permissions are the same I set manually